# Generate unique color from a string

Tags: .net, algorithm, colors

I have to draw some arbitrary strings in some *opaque* rectangular areas.
I need that the background color of that areas be unique foe a given string.

Say, if I draw "Paris" and "Paris1" their color should be different. But if I draw "Paris" in blue, each other "Paris" should be drawn in blue too.

I emphasize once again that the color should be opaque.

For this I found a simple solution:

```
rectangleBackColor = Color.FromArgb(myString.GetHashCode())
```

The problem is the opacity. I need to "eliminate" the "A"(alpha) component.

Now, such a code may work

```
  rectangleBackColor = Color.FromArgb(myString.GetHashCode())
  ' set the alpha value = 255 for an opaque color '
  rectangleBackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, rectangleBackColor)
```

but it can loose the string-color uniqueness.

Say, I have two different hashCodes (in hexa) `x AB 11 22 33` and `x FF 11 22 33`.
Setting `AB` to `FF` I makes to two different strings the same background color (`x FF 11 22 33`). This is not good.

Comment: Your approach (pre alpha change) is still not guaranteed for uniqueness - you're still mapping to 256^4 possible values as opposed to 256^3 when you limit the alpha channel.  I.e. you've not *lost* colour uniqueness, just increased the probability of a collision.  Since you're only allowing 256^3 different colour values, it's hard to see how you're going to do any better.

Comment: a solution could be to ***shift*** the obtained HashCode value `>> 2 hex values`, I search how to do it...

Comment: How many different string do you approximately have? Is it wise to chose the colors at total randomness?

Comment: @borrible: Ok, I understand. But however, in the given conditions I try to minimize at maximum the probability that 2 strings has the same value. If an other option that from Argb could be found, this willl be great.

Comment: @Magnus: I can't know *a priori*. This is the user who fills in some random short text (not larger the 15 chars).

Answer (score 2):

You can't generate unique colors for strings:

The RGB space has 24bits or 2^24-1 unique values (total of 16777215 colors).

The following code will print 16777220 unique strings (5 more than the number of colors):

```
for(int i=0; i<16777220 ; ++i) Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
```

So, if you take all the strings generated by the progam above and give then colors you must have at least 5 strings with repeating colors.

By the way, GetHashCode does not return unique values, just uniformly distributed, repeat the proof above with 32 bits (you will need to make i in the for loop uint and change the number to more than 4294967295, but those are the only changes) and you discover you can't get a unique value for every string in a 32bit value (or in any other fixed size value).

Your method is pretty good and repeat colors will probably be rare.

Comment: I'd like to find a way to shift the obtained hashcode right by 2 hex values. How can I do it?

Comment: @serhio - to shift x by 2 hex digits (=1byte = 8bits) you can do x=x>>8; - but I don't think it will do what you think it will (that is, this is unlikely to increase uniqueness it will just drop the last byte instead of the first one)

Answer (score 2):

Given that you cannot generate a truly unique integer to represent a string because of the difference in the size of the spaces they can represent, you could try:

```
uint noA = (unit)myString.GetHashCode() / 255; 
uint opaque = noA + 0xFF000000; 
rectangleBackColor = Color.FromArgb(opaque);
```

This should generate a (fairly) unique value for each string based on the hash code, with a the alpha component set to 255. Clearly, this can only generate 2^24 different values, and hence is not truly unique.

Edit: It should be noted this has exactly the same problem as your version but ignores the lowest 8 bits instead of the highest ones.

Comment: not need to ignore something. Say I have the hashcode `AB 11 22 33`, I want to make it `FF`+`AB 11 22 33` = `FF AB 11 22 33`. This should be a shift operation on int that does it.., So I preserve both `AB` and `33`

Comment: @serhio, Not quite sure what you mean there, but you can't fit `FF AB 11 22 33` in an `int` as it takes up more than 32 bits. You can have `FF 11 22 33` (your suggestion) or `FF AB 11 22` (mine), but either way you're going to lose some data from the original HashCode if you're trying to fit it in a 32bit value with 8 bits overwritten as 1s (the `FF`).

Comment: yeah... I understand. That's a pity that `FromArgb` is the only way to convert an integer to a color. )

Answer (score 1):

Hash is not unique in the first place. If you're not convinced, just consider how many more strings there is than hashcode. To begin with, hash code themselves are strings! Which means that if you were to attribute a different hash code to each strings, you would run out of hash code after going through all hash code.

Two strings having a same hashcode are called a collision. For a good hashcode, you can consider that the probability for two innocent strings to be in 1/#{size of your hash space}.

Another nice property, is that you expect any truncation of your hashcode to behave like that as well. Truncating your hash code is actually correct practise.

You will get for two given names a collision probability of around 1/16M.
If you have N-strings, however, you might encounter what is called the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).
The probability of observing at least 1 collision is much much greater. Somewhere near than N^2 / 16M.

Comment: I'd like to find a way to shift the obtained hashcode right by 2 hex values. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: say I have the hashcode `AB 11 22 33`, I want to make it `FF`+`AB 11 22 33` = `FF AB 11 22 33`. This should be a shift operation on int that does it...

Comment: @serhio what makes you think that shifting will give you a different result that what you already did?

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

1) If all your N strings are known before you start coloring, calculate a [Perfect Hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) (implementations in [C](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/perfect.html) and [C#](http://www.dupuis.me/node/9) here).   Then you can multiply each hash value by 256^3/N to spread the results over the color space.

2) If they are not known, you could resolve the collisions manually.  Something like this pseudocode:

```
tries = 5; //arbitrary number       
colorcode = myString.GetHashCode()&0xFFFFFF;
while ( Dictionary.containsKey(colorcode ) && 
        Dictionary.getValue(colorcode )!= myString &&
        tries-->0) {
    colorcode = ((colorcode+3) * 92821) &0xFFFFFF;  //rehash
}
if (tries) {
    Dictionary.insert(colorcode , myString);
} 
rectangleBackColor = Color.FromArgb(0xFF000000|colorcode );
```